# listagg with DISTINCT in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, listagg

I am struggling to find a good way to do a `DISTINCT` in `listagg` in redshift.

All I want to do is list the combination of product, but each row should return a list of distinct products.

**Example**

Desired output:

```
bulb, light
bulb, light, fan
```

instead of:

```
bulb, bulb, light
bulb, bulb, light, fan
```

Below is my SQL:

```
select
    tit.listagg  
from (
    SELECT
        username,
        listagg(node_name, ',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY node_name asc)
    FROM table
    Where node_type not like '%bla bla%'
    GROUP BY username
) as tit
group by listagg;
```

Comment: You can now use `DISTINCT` within `listagg` as an optional clause. More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows and then select the first one:

```
select username,
       listagg(case when seqnum = 1 then node_name end, ',') within group (order by node_name asc) 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username, node_name order by node_name) as seqnum
      from table t
      where node_type not like '%bla bla%' 
     ) t
group by username;
```

This uses the feature that `listagg()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: truly remarkable response and swift. Got it working. :)

Answer (score 3):

Redshift now supports LISTAGG DISTINCT so there is no need for a subquery: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-listagg-distinct/